# Annotating family of curves in `pgfplot`

Tags: pgfplots

I am using `pgfplot` to generate a family of curves. I would like to annotate each curve with the appropriate parameter as specified by `foreach` variable (in this case `temperatureRatio`). However I get an error when `Undefined control sequence` when I specify the label to `temperatureRatio` in the line `... node[right, pos=1, font=\small]{\temperatureRatio};`. How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \begin{axis}[ xmin=0, xmax=1,   ymin=0, ymax=5,
                  xlabel={$\eta$},   ylabel={$\mathbb{P} = \dot{W} /(\dot{m} C_p T_1)$}
                ]
        \foreach \temperatureRatio in {4,...,10}
        {
            \addplot[domain=10:50, samples = 41, samples y = 0, blue]
            ({ 1 - x^(-0.2857) }, { (1 - x^(-0.2857))*(\temperatureRatio - x^(0.2857))})
            node[right, pos=1, font=\small]{\temperatureRatio};
        }

        \addplot[domain = 3:10, samples = 20, samples y = 0, red]
        ({1 - x^(-1/2)},{(sqrt(x)-1)^2})
        node[left,pos=0]{$\mathbb{P}_{\text{max}}$};

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`pgfplots`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots) has different `foreach` macros with different characteristics. Here you have to use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \begin{axis}[ xmin=0, xmax=1,   ymin=0, ymax=5,
                  xlabel={$\eta$},   ylabel={$\mathbb{P} = \dot{W} /(\dot{m} C_p T_1)$}
                ]
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{4,...,10}
        {
            \addplot[domain=10:50, samples = 41, samples y = 0, blue]
            ({ 1 - x^(-0.2857) }, { (1 - x^(-0.2857))*(#1 - x^(0.2857))})
            node[right, pos=1, font=\small]{#1};
        }

        \addplot[domain = 3:10, samples = 20, samples y = 0, red]
        ({1 - x^(-1/2)},{(sqrt(x)-1)^2})
        node[left,pos=0]{$\mathbb{P}_{\text{max}}$};

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]